# The distribution of gaussian 2D vector given the distribution of average

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

My question:

> Let $X_1, X_2\sim N(\theta,1)$. Let $\bar X = aX_1+(1-a)X_2$ for $0<a<1$. Find the distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ given $\bar X$.

Update: My previous try is wrong. I delete it. Now based on the suggestion given below by @Did, I did the following:

Try to write done the distribution of $(X_1,\bar X)$. Again, both $X_1$ and $\bar X$ are normally distributed, where $\bar X\sim N(\theta,a')$ where constant $a'=\sqrt{a^2+(1-a)^2}$. Clearly, $X_1$ and $\bar X$ are not independent so we have to write done the correlation so that I can use bivariate normal density.

To compute correlation, we notice that 
$$
\operatorname{cov}(X_1,\bar X)=\operatorname{cov}(X_1,aX_1+(1-a)X_2) = a\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_1)+(1-a) \operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2) = a
$$
Thus, we have the distribution of $(X_1,\bar X)$ is the bivariate normal distribution with mean vector $(\theta,\theta)$, variance $\sigma_1=1$ and $\bar \sigma = a'$, and $\rho = a$. Hence, it has pdf
$$
f(x_1,\bar x) = \frac{1}{2\pi {a'}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[\frac{(x_1-\theta)^2}{1} +\frac{(\bar x-\theta)^2}{{a'}^2} - \frac{2\rho(x_1-\theta)(\bar x-\theta)}{{a'}}    \right] \right)
$$
and hence the conditional distribution $f(x_1|\bar x)$ can be obtained by 
$$
\frac{f(x_1,\bar x)}{f(\bar x)}=\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[\frac{(x_1-\theta)^2}{1} +\frac{(\bar x-\theta)^2}{{a'}^2} - \frac{2\rho(x_1-\theta)(\bar x-\theta)}{{a'}}    \right]+\frac{(\bar x-\theta)^2}{2{a'}^2} \right)
$$

Comment: "I'm wondering is that my argument make sense?" Not much. If $p_{X_1,X_2,\bar X}$ refers to the PDF of $W=(X_1,X_2,\bar X)$, then the trouble is that $W$ has no PDF since $W\in H$ almost surely, where $H$ denotes the plane in the $(x,y,z)$-space of equation $z=ax+(1-a)y$. On the other hand, assuming $(X_1,X_2)$ are i.i.d. then $(X_1,\bar X)$ has a PDF. Can you compute the conditional distribution of $X_1$ conditioned on $\bar X$? It might help to introduce $Z=(1-a)X_1-aX_2$.

Comment: @Did I upload my post. Please have a look!

Comment: If the distributions of $(X_1,\bar X$ is $\mu$ then the distribution of $W=(X_1,X_2,\bar X)$ is $\nu$ defined by $$\nu(dxdydz)=\mu(dxdz)\delta_{(z-ax)/(1-a)}(dy).$$ The Dirac part, which reflects the fact that $W\in H$ almost surely, might be some reason why you find this nondirect.

Comment: By the way, did you actually compute the distribution of $(X_1,\bar X)$ then the conditional distribution of $X_1$ conditioned on $\bar X$?

Comment: Yea I did, it is another normal distribution right? But, could you write more information about the equation you are writing there? I kind of lost though...

Comment: If you did compute the distribution of $(X_1,\bar X)$, please include in your question the detail of these computations and the result you get.

Comment: @Did done adding

Comment: Right. There are some mistakes in your computations but more important is: in the end, which distribution do you say that $X_1$ conditional on $\bar X=\bar x$ is following? Normal with mean $____$ and variance $____$?

Comment: Another option is to follow the hint in my very first comment and to note that $X_1=(a\bar X+(1-a)Z)/b^2$ with $b^2=a^2+(1-a)^2$. Since $\bar X$ and $Z$ are independent, this leads directly to $X_1$ conditional on $\bar X=\bar x$ being normal with mean $a\bar x/b^2$ and variance $(1-a)^2\sigma^2(Z)/b^4=(1-a)^2/b^2$. Thus, you have a way to check the result you will obtain with the computational approach in your post...

Comment: @Did. I see. So in this way I will have $X_1$ condition on $\bar X$ and $X_2$ condition on $\bar X$ and hence $(X_1,X_2)$ condition on $\bar X$ would be just the multiplication of them because the independence right?

Comment: Since $\operatorname{var}(\bar X) = a^2+(1-a)^2$ and $\operatorname{var}(X_1)=1$ and $\operatorname{cov}(X_1,\bar X) = a$, you have $\rho\left(X_1,\bar X\right) = \dfrac a {\sqrt 1 \cdot \sqrt{a^2+(1-a)^2}} \vphantom{\dfrac{\displaystyle\int}\int}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: **Not. At. All.** If you still believe after my first and second comments that $(X_1,X_2)$ is independent conditionally on $\bar X$, what can I further explain?

Comment: @Did sorry... so after I compute the distribution of $(X_1|\bar X)$, I then can use your dirac translation to obtain $(X_1, X_2|\bar X)$ right? What I have in mind before is, since both $(X_1|\bar X)$ and $(X_2|\bar X)$ are normal, I can again use bivariate normal to have $(X_1,X_2|\bar X)$ by again computing the correlation between them? I know they are not independent... Sorry for my stupid mistake...